# Adding a new key value to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. I would like to add the values of the second array to the first array as key value. This is the array I have

//Main Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [commodity] => Abacavir (ABC) 300mg Tabs
            [allocated] => 
            [balance] => 1388
            [mos] => 3
            [year] => 2018
            [month] => May
            [drug_id] => 1
            [data_date] => 2018-05-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [commodity] => Abacavir/Lamivudine (ABC/3TC) 120/60mg FDC Tabs
            [allocated] => 
            [balance] => 1185
            [mos] => 26
            [year] => 2018
            [month] => May
            [drug_id] => 4
            [data_date] => 2018-05-01
        )
)
```

//MOS ARRAY

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

//results desired

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [commodity] => Abacavir (ABC) 300mg Tabs
            [allocated] => 
            [balance] => 1388
            [mos] => 3
            [year] => 2018
            [month] => May
            [drug_id] => 1
            [data_date] => 2018-05-01
            [amc] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [commodity] => Abacavir/Lamivudine (ABC/3TC) 120/60mg FDC Tabs
            [allocated] => 
            [balance] => 1185
            [mos] => 26
            [year] => 2018
            [month] => May
            [drug_id] => 4
            [data_date] => 2018-05-01
            [amc] => 4
        )
)
```

What I have tried so far

```
foreach ($sub_res as $key => $res) {            
    $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT  $amcfunction($drug_id,$no_of_mos,'$date'$amc) amc")->result_array();
    $sub_res[$key]['amc'] = $query2[0]['amc'];

}
```

With this it is only appending amc to the last array. Any Suggestions?  $sub_res is the result of the first array that i am adding amc to

Comment: It does sound like you want array_merge?

 http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php But I might be missunderstadning you.

Comment: @NigelRen I have edited the question, I want to add second array values to the first as 'amc'

Comment: @Virre Im looking for something different, not a merge

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate over your array?

```
foreach ($main as &$item) {
    $item['amc'] = array_shift($mos);
}
unset($item);
```

`array_shift` will just remove the first item from the `$mos` array and add to each iteration of `$main`.
Notice that I used the ampersand - `&` - to create a reference and, as a result of that, I also unset the item so that there are not hanging references.

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach` would be pretty quick for this.

Here is a sample, simplified version:

```
// simplified main array
$main[] = array('commodity' => 'Abacavir (ABC) 300mg Tabs');
$main[] = array('commodity' => 'Abacavir/Lamivudine (ABC/3TC) 120/60mg FDC Tabs');

// MOS Array
$mos = array(3,4);

foreach($mos as $k => $v) {
    $main[$k]['amc'] = $v;
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($main);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

And the result:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>  array(2) {
        ["commodity"]=> string(25) "Abacavir (ABC) 300mg Tabs"
        ["amc"]=> int(3)
    }
    [1]=>  array(2) {
        ["commodity"]=> string(47) "Abacavir/Lamivudine (ABC/3TC) 120/60mg FDC Tabs"
        ["amc"]=> int(4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
foreach ($sub_res as $key => $res) {            
   $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT  $amcfunction($drug_id,$no_of_mos,'$date'$amc) amc")->result_array();
   $sub_res[$key] = array_merge($res, ['amc' => $query2[0]]);

}
```